# Python Django RestFramework route trigger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'am building an API using python 2.7 and django 1.7 and I'm facing a problem. I'm not an expert in Rest Framework but I understand the basic mechanisms.

I can resume my problem by giving you an example. I have a route lets say

```
/api/project/
```

Django Rest Framework provides me all basic operations for this route and I don't need to write them e.g:

```
POST, GET, PUT, DELETE => /api/project/
```

The fact is, I want to do some operation when I create a new project. I want to add the id of the user who has created the new project.

I want to add some kind of trigger/callback to the create function:

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

I want to keep the internal behavior of Rest Framework (I don't want to rewrite the route functions), but I want the route to do extra stuff and I need the request object in my trigger/callback. Something like

```
def callback(request, instance):
    instance.created_by = request.user
    instance.save()
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean request.user?

Comment: I need request.user and the created object. I've edited my post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add creator_id field to your serializer as well as to model represented by the resource. Then you can do something like this in your view:-

```
import copy

class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

      ...

      def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          data = copy.deepcopy(request.data)
          data['creator_id'] = request.user.id
          request._data = data

          return super(ProjectViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your time, I'll test it right now